# Static/Constructor Java AWS Lambda function initialization with context information

Tags: java, aws-lambda

I have a lambda, written in Java that accesses a Neo4J instance (could be literally almost any external resource though).  I can make this work in a rough fashion readily enough, but I would ideally like to:

a) Create a singleton driver instance either statically or via the constructor
AND
b) Use environment variables to inject credentials/endpoints etc

Is there any static way of accessing environment variables during class construction?

Am I stuck with an "if driver == null" initialization at the start of every request, or am I missing something important?

Dave

Answer (score 0):

Truly, I am not bright today...

Lambda environment variables are accessed just like any other variable...

System.getenv("DAVETEST")